# trying to use the "search" method but I still have an error

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, swift4

Hi this is my first time trying to use the search method, I am using the Search Bar Guide on Apple Developer website but I have this issue and can't seem to figure it out. I have my Data stored in a Class DataServices and I have my tableView cells working just perfect in my ViewController, but I can't seem to figure out what I am supposed to return in the search method to complete the method, When I do it just as the search Guide instructions Xcode screams at me. Can you bless me with your knowlegde

```
class ListVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var filteredData: [List]!
    let data = DataServices.instance.getList()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        filteredData = data
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DataServices.instance.getList().count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListingCell") as? ListCell {
            let listing = DataServices.instance.getList()[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateView(lists: listing)
            return cell
        }else {
            return ListCell()
        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data: data.filter({ (List: String) -> Bool in
            return List.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil    

> Value of type 'List' has no member 'range' is the error I get

        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    }

}
```

class DataServices {
    static let instance = DataServices()

```
private let currentList = [
    List(firstText: "Name", secondText: "Shannon"),
    List(firstText: "Car", secondText: "Infinity"),
    List(firstText: "City", secondText: "Brandon"),
    List(firstText: "Wife", secondText: "Naedra"),
    List(firstText: "Child", secondText: "Shantae"),
    List(firstText: "Job", secondText: "Driver"),
    List(firstText: "Cell", secondText: "iPhone"),
    List(firstText: "Computer", secondText: "Imac")

]

func getList() -> [List] {
return currentList
}
```

}

struct List {

```
private (set) public var toptitle: String
private (set) public var bottomtitle: String

init(firstText: String, secondText: String) {
    self.toptitle = firstText
    self.bottomtitle = secondText
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question to show the definition of `List` - You want `$0.someProperty` where `someProperty` is the string property you want to filter by.  The code you have now is trying to call `range` on the `List` class.

Comment: Also, does `DataServices.instance.getList()` perform a network operation? If so then you shouldn't do that repeatedly - You should get the data once

Comment: DataServices.instance.getList() is from a swift file that I store the data, here is the code

Comment: I added the files with the codes to show more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure parameters represent instances not types and the `filter` closure applied to an array takes only one argument. The checking for empty string is redundant.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = data.filter ({ (list) -> Bool in
        return list.firstText.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
               list.secondText.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or with simplified syntax

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = data.filter { $0.firstText.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
                                 $0.secondText.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }  
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

I recommend to declare `filteredData` as non-optional empty array to avoid unnecessary unwrapping

```
var filteredData = [List]()
```

and force downcast the cell, if the code crashes it reveals a design mistake.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListingCell", for: indexPath) as! ListCell
```

If you want constants in your `List` struct simply write

```
struct List {
    let toptitle: String
    let bottomtitle: String
}
```

you get the initializer for free. `private (set) var` is very *objective-c-ish*

Finally getting the same (static) list on each call of `cellForRow` is unnecessarily expensive, get the item from `data`

```
let listing = data[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: it is still throwing me a error stating that the value of type List has no member 'range'

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = data.filter({ (string) -> Bool in
            return string.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you have to check the range of the string properties. I updated the answer.